# Location of Labels with Crossing Arrows in Commuative Diagrams with tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I want to add a commutative diagram and started using tilkcd today, but having a trouble with the location of labels attached to an arrow when two arrows cross over with each other.

Here's a commutative diagram in Mac Lane's Cateogory Theory textbook for associativity.

[image]

Here's my trial for it.

[image]

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge, row sep=huge]
a \arrow[r, "f\circ g\circ h"] \arrow[d, "h"'] \arrow[dr, "g\circ h" very near start] & d \\
b \arrow[r, "g"] \arrow[ur, "f\circ g" very near start] & c \arrow[u, "f"']
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the labels attached to the arrows in the middle part look out of place.
I tried 'very near start' and 'inner sep=0ex' but I couldn't make it look better.
Simple problem but any help is much appreciated.

[Edited] Attached the relevant pictures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3cm, row sep=huge]
a \arrow[r, "f\circ (g\circ h) = (f\circ g)\circ h"] \arrow[d, "h"'] \arrow[dr, "g\circ h", pos=0.2,swap] & d \\
b \arrow[r, "g",swap] \arrow[ur, "f\circ g", pos=0.8,swap,crossing over] & c \arrow[u, "f"']
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- You can gain finer control on the position of labels using the `pos=<value>` option.
- There's the `crossing over` option for an arrow that crosses over another.
- I increased the `column sep` to `3cm`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one question though as a beginner; can I reduce the space between the label and the arrow a bit more? I tried something like \arrow[dr, "g\circ h", pos=0.2, inner sep=0.1ex] but 'pos' and 'inner sep' don't seem to apply at the same time(only pos part).

Comment: @TaxxiDriver You should use `outer sep=-2pt` or alike. However, you might try `\arrow[crossing over]{ur}[near end,description]{f\circ g}` or `\arrow[crossing over]{ur}[pos=.8,sloped]{f\circ g}` as well.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thank you very much. Now my diagram looks much better!